# Reattaching a detached instance: hibernate lock()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, locking

I'm a bit confused. I don't understand why the changes made before lock()/buildLockRequest() are propagated to the database.

In this example my initial price is set and should not be updated to the database. But it's actually updated if I print it out. Or have things changed? Book is using Hibernate 3 and I'm using Hibernate v3.6.10.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Item item = (Item) session.get(Item.class, new Long(1));

tx.commit();
session.close();

Session sessionTwo = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx2 = sessionTwo.beginTransaction();
// Changes made before the call to lock() aren’t propagated to the database
item.setInitialPrice(new BigDecimal(179));

// sessionTwo.lock(item, LockMode.NONE);
sessionTwo.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(item);
item.setDescription("This playstation 3 is in a fine state");
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setLenient(false);
gc.set(2015, 0, 31, 9, 12, 34);

item.setEndDate(gc.getTime());

item = (Item) sessionTwo.get(Item.class, new Long(1));

tx2.commit();
sessionTwo.close();

logger.debug(item.toString()); // still changes are made to initialPrice property
```

From [Java Persistence With Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/)

> In this case, it *does* matter whether changes are made before or after the object has
>   been reattached. Changes made before the call to lock() aren’t propagated to
>   the database, you use it only if you’re sure the detached instance hasn’t been
>   modified. This method only guarantees that the object’s state changes from
>   detached to persistent and that Hibernate will manage the persistent object again.
>   Of course, any modifications you make to the object once it’s in managed persistent
>   state require updating of the database.
>   We discuss Hibernate lock modes in the next chapter. By specifying Lock-
>   Mode.NONE here, you tell Hibernate not to perform a version check or obtain any
>   database-level locks when reassociating the object with the Session. If you specified
>   LockMode.READ, or LockMode.UPGRADE, Hibernate would execute a SELECT
>   statement in order to perform a version check (and to lock the row(s) in the database
>   for updating).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sessionTwo.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(item);`?

Comment: Yes, forgot that. The book is using the deprecated method lock().

Comment: Did you try to step through your code in a debugger? Tell hibernate to output SQL statements, so you can see, when the changes are written to the database.

Comment: I have `hibernate.show_sql` on. It does a select and than just does an update at the end when the transaction commits. InitialPrice shouldn't be updated. I modified the example of the book to just see if it does. So lock() reattaches the detached object but why does the book says that changes made before the lock aren't propagated but in this case it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Changes made before the call to lock() aren’t propagated to the database
item.setInitialPrice(new BigDecimal(179));
```

This is the expected behavior, since the item object is detached, and detached objects are not subject to [automatic dirty checking](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/), so no change is propagated to the database in this particular state.

Once you reattach it:

```
sessionTwo.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(item);
```

the dirty checking will be applied at flush time. When you reattach an entity, Hibernate issues an SQL SELECT to fetch the latest entity state, which will be used at flush time to compare it against the in-memory object data.

That's why after lock (even for LockOptions.NONE), you see the changes propagated.

If you comment the lock method, then no change will be propagated, since the second session
is unaware of the detached item.